# What is the difference between `stack clean` and removing the `.stack-work` directory?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

#### 1 Context

I am involved in a Haskell project that involves lots of C-bits and FFI. So I find myself frequently running and re-running commands like

```
$ stack build
$ stack build --force-dirty
$ stack clean
$ rm ./.stack-work
```

over and over in order for the C-bits to be linked properly to the Haskell bits. Put differently, sometimes things just work when running `stack build`, and sometimes they don't (in which case I'm forced to cycle through the above commands over and over until my project builds properly).

This means I don't have a proper understanding of how `stack` (through `ghc`) assembles the C-bits before assembling the Haskell bits.  So here is one question to help me start clearing up my confusion:

#### 2 Question

Are there any noteworthy difference between running `stack clean` and deleting the contents of the `.stack-work` directory? Are there cases where deleting the `.stack-work` directory is needed as a good precaution to ensure that you are actually running a clean build?

Comment: If you often run into linking issues with `stack build`, please [create a bug report](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/new)!

Comment: In a single package project `stack clean --full` is basically an alias for `rm .stack-work`.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1609) recorded how the `--full` option of `stack clean` was created.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by reading the source here:

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/src/Stack/Clean.hs

There are two levels, full and shallow. I think shallow seems to be the default. It seems to be able to clean specific packages, or if you don't provide no options at all, it'll clean everything but extra-deps in local packages.